# Which is correct, "all night" or "all-night" and why?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

The sentence is, "...we've been up-all-night writing reports..."

Is it all night or all-night, and could someone explain why?

Comment: i think the first one is right but I'm not sure. english language and usage SE will know more about this type of question, but I see no reason it is off topic for writing SE.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion

Comment: I think it would be "I had to stay up all night," but it would be "It was an all-night party. so we pulled an all-nighter." In the first it is functionally separate words, but in the second it is functionally a single word/phrase. I'm not an English major, though. Try English SE.

Comment: Where were you all night?  At an all-night study session.

Comment: We were up all night at an all-night party.

Comment: We have an all-night canteen in our campus.

Answer (score 2):

While I am not a grammarian, here is my answer.

The dash between the two words indicates that they are to be taken as unit as they are applied to something that follows. For example, I met Salena at an all-night diner. What kind of diner was it? An **all-night** diner, rather than a diner that was both all and night.

While the dash is not a horrible, no good, breach of grammatical usage, I would prefer *I stayed up all night fixing the broken database* over *I stayed up all-night fixing the broken database*. For me, the second form triggers a "missing step" response (or, if you like, a missing-step response); I would expect that the all-night usage would modify something that follows but there is nothing following that would make a reasonable target.

But note that if your target audience would fall over laughing if they were to read this answer, you should do it the way that said target audience expects it to be done.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

The answer should be "we've been up all night writing reports".

You only use hyphens between words when there are multiple words that are supposed to behave as one.

For instance, you could say "We have an all-night party." "All-night" has a hyphen in it because it is functioning as one adjective modifying "party".

Another example is "I attended an eight-year-old boy's birthday party." "Eight-year-old" is behaving as one adjective modifying "boy", so it is hyphenated.

A third example is "There are many moss-covered rocks in the forest." "Moss-covered" is hyphenated since it is behaving as one adjective modifying "rocks".

Comment: The more precise formulation is that you use a hyphen for compound adjectives but not for compound nouns. So fire trucks are often painted fire-truck red. There are borderline cases, e.g., some writers will hyphenate an adverb-adjective pair (newly-minted words) while others will not.